# Local maven package is not in import list

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies, classpath

I am trying to import a class in my java code. The class is from a local maven repository. Is this possible?

My POM file includes:

```
<dependency
  <groupId>com.datuma.jbpm</groupId>
  <artifactId>HR</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is the jar in the maven library for my project: 
[image: Here it is my the projects Maven library (HR)]

However, when try to import it in my class, it is not found:

```
import com.datuma.jbpm.*
```

There are not any packages in this project, which was the problem, Thanks

[image]

Comment: Have you updated your maven project so that maven can download your dependencies?

Comment: You import a class and not a jar from a class. Give the exact error please.

Comment: There's an expansion arrow to the left of that jar name. Open it and post what you see for the jar contents.

Comment: Have you checked if the package name is correct ? Maybe a difference between groupId and package name?

Comment: Hey guys. chrylis, I checked the contects of jar and there are no packages at all in it, so it was never going to work. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer my own question, the class I was trying to import was not in the repository, and I was able to determine that it was not by expanding the contents of the jar.